# NativeScript - How to add plugin to "angular-seed" template

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've cloned the following Github repo to bootstrap my NativeScript application.

https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed

I now want to run to the following command to add a toast message plugin.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-toast
```

However, I get the following error when I run the command.

**No project found at or above 'C:\src\angular-seed' and neither was a --path specified.**

I've tried running the command from the directory with the package.json file and the "src/client" directory as well.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repository https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed support only Angular.

You should be using this repository Angular seed advanced
https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced

To install the plugin:

```
cd nativescript && tns plugin add nativescript-toast
```

Comment: I've cloned angular-seed-advanced and tried the same command in the directory where the package.json resides and also the "client" directory...got the same error message.  Do you know what I need to specify for the "path" command line param?

Comment: the tns command will work only on a nativescript project and not just angular

Comment: My bad, I didn't read the post properly...need to run it from the nativescript directory

Comment: @TheMagnificent11 I realized the same thing after several mins. I overlooked your comment as well. You can probably add it as a separate answer to this question.